# Getting "local module" working in Vite that was working with webpack

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, vite

I recently inherited a frontend project with a slow build and replaced `react-scripts` with Vite. This was more or less pain-free, apart from this Typescript error:

```
`TS2307: Cannot find module 'app-interfaces' or its corresponding type declarations.`
```

This `app-interfaces` module is actually more or less a "path alias" or "local module" or whatever you may call it, that actually references a type definition file under `src/bin/models/Interfaces.d.ts` (don't ask me about the path - I don't know).

This `Interfaces.d.ts` file is not imported or referenced *anywhere*, but it starts like this:

```
declare module 'app-interfaces' {
  import {
    UserGender,
    SubcriptionPlans,
    SubscriptionPlanInterval,
    EventTypes,
    DayTypes,
    ApiMethods,
    ExerciseTypes,
    SessionTypes,
    EventProps,
  } from './StaticTypes';

  // API
  declare namespace Api {
    export interface Config {
      url: URL;
      options?: {
        method: ApiMethods;
...
```

Other parts of the code refer to this module like this: `import {App, Events, User} from 'app-interfaces';`

I cannot actually find any references to how this works at all ... I do not understand how others can reference its types using `import {App} from 'app-interfaces';` when nothing ever references the filename, and I tried to `eject` the app to inspect the webpack config, but I really did not get any smarter ...

Is there a way I can reuse this "trick" of making TSC know about all definitions as `app-interfaces` in my Vite setup's TS config to avoid redoing all the imports all over the app? The alternative is to replace it with explicit long import paths everywhere (like `../../../src/bin/models/Interfaces.d.ts`. While manageable, it's a bit of a chore ...